# Sandboxing Mathematica on Unix

Tags: unix, wolfram-mathematica

Is anyone able to run Mathematica under ptrace sandbox?
I'm able to get Matlab to work with it, but Mathematica seems to freeze.

The following is supposed to produce `img.png` with all calls ptraced, freezes

```
strace -f test.m
```

test.m:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
img=Plot3D[Im[ArcSin[(x + I y)^4]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None,PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.5]],ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Red}];
Export["img.png", img]
```

crossposted to Mathematica mailing list

Comment: You're talking about ptrace, but the call you show is to strace.

Comment: @belisarius Might be, but `strace` seems to be a function similar to `ptrace`, so one should make clear which one causes the problem.

Comment: ptrace is a kernel mechanism for intercepting commands, strace is a monitoring utility that uses ptrace, systrace is a security sandbox that uses ptrace. If something doesn't work under strace, it probably won't work under any ptrace utility

Comment: Is this really about programming?  I think it might be better on SuperUser.

Comment: The problem is that there are no Mathematica users on SuperUser. Might be better to ask this on Mathematica stack overflow once it's launched -- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15787/mathematica

Comment: @yaroslav I really hope it will happen, but current traffic in the Mathematica tag isn't so high as to warrant a separate Mathematica group.

Answer (score 1):

This just works fine for me.
I use some recent debian-based Linux:

```
rolfm@gluon:~/mathgroup$ uname -a

Linux gluon 2.6.38-10-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 15:07:17 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Hi Rolf, nice to see you on stackoverflow. I agree, @Yaro's code works fine on my Ubuntu 11.04 system.

Comment: Thanks for the checks, none of you use distributed licenses right? (where you must specify license server)

Comment: Another q, what is your strace version "strace -V"

Comment: I use a normal/local Mma license. `strace -- version 4.5.20`

Comment: strace -- version 4.5.20 Usually I use a local M-license, but I just tested with a license server of a reseller and it also works fine. Which Linux are you using?

Comment: This answer should probably be a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) to your previous answer. Also, you've managed to set up two different accounts [1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/887505/rolf-mertig) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/889638/rolf-mertig) I've asked for them to be merged for you...

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts. You should not have any more difficulty commenting or editing.

Comment: @Yaro it also works for me with mma using a license server; strace is 4.5.20